# Android java button image changes when clicked

Tags: java, android

I cant seem to get my code to work. I keep getting a error.

I made a selector.xml with this code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loginbuttondn" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loginbutton" />
</selector>
```

heres my actual code

```
package monaiz.net.periscope.periscope;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                    v.setSelected(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Im trying to get it so that when i click the button it has a click down effect showing the other image

Im getting a error here:

Im still getting a error on this line `v.setSelected(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);`

on the "v."

code for my button

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="830px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loginbutton"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml code for your button?

Comment: Thats your issue. You have not set the selecter as the background but the image and as the source of your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Use `state_pressed`:

drawable/selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loginbuttondn" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/loginbutton" />
</selector>
```

---

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"/>
```

Comment: Im still getting a error on this line  v.setSelected(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN); saying its needs to be declared final

Comment: You actually don't even need to implement an `OnTouchListener` if you set up your selector correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector needs to look like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loginbuttondn" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loginbutton" />
</selector>
```

Call this login_button_selector.xml and put it in your /res/drawable folder
Now use it like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="830px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/login_button_selector"/>
```

When the view is in "pressed" state, it will match the first item in the selector. When it is not in "pressed" state, it will just match the second item in the selector.

Comment: Im still getting a error on this line v.setSelected(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN); saying its needs to be declared final

Comment: Well, that's a different issue. It happens because you try to access "v" from an anonymous class. If you change the method signature "public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)" to "public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event)" it will go away. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you should try and use a click listener on the views themselves, not the activity.

Comment: Im trying to make it so that when you press on a imageview button it looks like its pressed down from the 2nd image

Comment: Try to just delete the onTouch method and try the selector approach described in the answer.